# XPATH not showing any data

Tags: xml, xpath

Im using the xpath below to select all data in the path, everything looks good to me however it doesn't output any data only the text, and has no errors. Any ideas whats wrong? *The is just text to get over the limit of posting ignore it*

```
concat('Which Customers dealt with which branch: ', //customers/customer/cbranch[@bid]/text())
```

XML

```
<customers>
        <customer cid="1">
            <firstname>Sam</firstname>
            <lastname>Mitchell</lastname>
            <gender>Male</gender>
            <dob>1991-12-12</dob>
            <email>sammitch@hotmail.co.uk</email>
            <address>
                161, South Road, Nidrie, W79 8WG
            </address>
            <tel>07811119542</tel>
            <cbranch bid="2" />
        </customer>
        <customer cid="2">
            <firstname>Chris</firstname>
            <lastname>Bernards</lastname>
            <gender>Male</gender>
            <dob>1976-04-05</dob>
            <email>berny5476@gmail.com</email>
            <address>
                179, Park Street, Inverness, Z27 0YU
            </address>
            <tel>07565641232</tel>
            <cbranch bid="3" />
        </customer>
        <customer cid="3">
            <firstname>Markus</firstname>
            <lastname>Imrie</lastname>
            <gender>Male</gender>
            <dob>1995-06-20</dob>
            <email>markus117@gmail.com</email>
            <address>
                49, Ferry Plaza, Dunfermline, D24 1VD
            </address>
            <tel>07712312488</tel>
            <cbranch bid="1" />
        </customer>
        <customer cid="4">
            <firstname>Ryan</firstname>
            <lastname>Murray</lastname>
            <gender>Male</gender>
            <dob>1995-06-23</dob>
            <email>murray_ryan@hotmail.co.uk</email>
            <address>
                186, Skye Avenue, Inverness, K56 0MX
            </address>
            <tel>07508611248</tel>
            <cbranch bid="6" />
        </customer>
        <customer cid="5">
            <firstname>Alice</firstname>
            <lastname>Montgomery</lastname>
            <gender>Female</gender>
            <dob>1985-01-01</dob>
            <email>alicemont@btinternet.com</email>
            <address>
                158, John Road, Clydebank, P23 8DW
            </address>
            <tel>07560002143</tel>
            <cbranch bid="8" />
        </customer>
        <customer cid="6">
            <firstname>Daniel</firstname>
            <lastname>West</lastname>
            <gender>Male</gender>
            <dob>1966-06-06</dob>
            <email>danielwest@gmail.com</email>
            <address>
                94, Regent Avenue, Perth, S34 9TE
            </address>
            <tel>07454651321</tel>
            <cbranch bid="4" />
        </customer>
        <customer cid="7">
            <firstname>George</firstname>
            <lastname>Burnett</lastname>
            <gender>Male</gender>
            <dob>1978-09-06</dob>
            <email>gb205@hotmail.co.uk</email>
            <address>
                76, South Lane, Aberdeen, V28 0TF
            </address>
            <tel>07562537541</tel>
            <cbranch bid="9" />
        </customer>
        <customer cid="8">
            <firstname>Katie</firstname>
            <lastname>Drummond</lastname>
            <gender>Female</gender>
            <dob>1993-11-16</dob>
            <email>katiedrummond@gmail.com</email>
            <address>
                45, West Road, Edinburgh, A79 2EG
            </address>
            <tel>07654546123</tel>
            <cbranch bid="5" />
        </customer>
        <customer cid="9">
            <firstname>Lizzie</firstname>
            <lastname>Alderan</lastname>
            <gender>Female</gender>
            <dob>1976-05-28</dob>
            <email>lizziealderan@gmail.com</email>
            <address>
                49, Ferry Plaza, Dunfermline, D24 1VD
            </address>
            <tel>07651246572</tel>
            <cbranch bid="7" />
        </customer>
        <customer cid="10">
            <firstname>Rebecca</firstname>
            <lastname>Almond</lastname>
            <gender>Female</gender>
            <dob>1997-03-30</dob>
            <email>beckyalmond@gmail.com</email>
            <address>
                13, Harris Place, BathgateGlasgow, E74 2MR
            </address>
            <tel>07876123451</tel>
            <cbranch bid="8" />
        </customer>
    </customers>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `<cbranch/>` has no `text()`? What are you expecting to return?

For example use this xpath if you want to return the email of everyone who is worked on `@bid` 2

```
concat('Which Customers dealt with which branch: ', /customers/customer[cbranch/@bid = '2']/email/text())
```

which will return

```
Which Customers dealt with which branch: sammitch@hotmail.co.uk
```